# Modify Node Group Input order with Python

Tags: node-editor

I just want to re order nod group inputs like set entry "bob mix" to entry number 4.

I can't find the way to select node group inputs or output by ID? index?input?
Just spend hours looking for it and can't find any example or doc solution :/

for i in bpy.data.node_groups:

```
        if i.name== "bob mix":
           i.index == 4 ?
           i.input == 4 ?
           i.ID == 4 ?
           i.socket == 4 ?
```

please help